# importXML in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, xml, import

I have a project website that contains a roster page that pulls in XML data. This used to work fine in all browsers and now only works in Chrome. In IE11 it appears that the importXML function isn't working as the page looks as it should with the exception of no roster data in it at all.

Can someone please help me with this? I wasn't able to find anything in my searches.

```
  <tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td width="32" height="108" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6D6EB"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="pagetext" -->
    <td colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6D6EB" id="top">
    <div id="content">
    <div id="rosterTabBar">
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li id="full"><a href="javascript:void(createRoster())">full roster</a></li>
            <!--<li id="byprot"><a href="javascript:void(rosterByProtocol())">by protocol</a></li>-->
            <li id="bysite"><a href="javascript:void(rosterBySite())">by institution</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h2>Roster</h2>
        <form id="rosterForm" name="rosterForm" action="" onsubmit="filteredRoster(document.forms.rosterForm.field.options[document.forms.rosterForm.field.selectedIndex].value,document.forms.rosterForm.query.value);return false;">
            <input id="query" name="lname" type="text" size="16" maxlength="128" />
            <select id="field" name="field">
                <option value="all">All Fields</option>
                <option value="name">Name</option>
                <option value="role">Study Role</option>
                <option value="company">Institution</option>
                <option value="dept">Department</option>
                <option value="address">Address</option>
                <option value="number">Phone/Fax</option>
                <option value="email">Email</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="filteredRoster(document.forms.rosterForm.field.options[document.forms.rosterForm.field.selectedIndex].value,document.forms.rosterForm.query.value)" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(this.print())"><img style="border:none;" src="../../images/printer.gif" alt="Print" /> Print</a>
        </form>
        <a href="javascript:void(expandRoster())">expand all</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(collapseRoster())">collapse all</a><br />
        <br />
        <div id="listRoot">
        </div>
        <div id="rosterRoot">
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        <!--
            importXML('roster.xml','storeRoster');
        //-->
        </script>
    </div>
    </td>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

[image: The roster doesn't appear here, where it should appear.]

Using the Console in IE, I'm getting this error:

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference
File: rosterHandler.js, Line: 39, Column: 2**

And this is the portion in rosterHandler.js:

```
function storeRoster(xmlDoc) {
                if( xmlDoc.documentElement && xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName && xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'HTML' ) {
                                setTimeout('//alert(\'For no apparent reason, your browser has turned the clean XML into HTML based garbage.\\nScript aborted.\');',50); return; }

                rosterStore = xmlDoc;
                var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('member');

                for(var i = 0;i< x.length;i++) {
                                if(x[i].getElementsByTagName('firstname')[0].firstChild || x[i].getElementsByTagName('lastname')[0].firstChild) {
                                                rosterEntries[i] = new RosterEntry(x[i]);
                                }
                }
```

importXML:

```
// JavaScript Document
var MWJ_ldD = [];
function importXML( oURL, oFunct, oNoRand, oDelay ) {
                //alert('making xml');
                //note: in XML importing event handlers, 'this' refers to window
                if( !oNoRand ) { oURL += ( ( oURL.indexOf('?') + 1 ) ? '&' : '?' ) + ( new Date() ).getTime(); } //prevent cache
                if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
                                //alternate XMLHTTP request - Gecko, Safari 1.2+ and Opera 7.6+
                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length] = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length-1].onreadystatechange = new Function( 'if( MWJ_ldD['+(MWJ_ldD.length-1)+'].readyState == 4 && MWJ_ldD['+(MWJ_ldD.length-1)+'].status < 300 ) { '+oFunct+'(MWJ_ldD['+(MWJ_ldD.length-1)+'].responseXML); }' );
                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length-1].open("GET", oURL, true);
                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length-1].send(null);
                                return true;
                }
                if( !navigator.__ice_version && window.ActiveXObject ) {
                                //the Microsoft way - IE 5+/Win (ICE produces errors and fails to use try-catch correctly)
                                try { //IE Mac has the property window.ActiveXObject but produces errors if you try and use it
                                                try { var tho = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM' ); //newer
                                                } catch(e) { var tho = new ActiveXObject( 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP' ); } //older
                                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length] = tho;
                                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length-1].onreadystatechange = new Function( 'if( MWJ_ldD['+(MWJ_ldD.length-1)+'].readyState == 4 ) { '+oFunct+'(MWJ_ldD['+(MWJ_ldD.length-1)+']); }' );
                                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length-1].load(oURL);
                                                return true;
                                } catch(e) {}
                }
                if( document.createElement && document.childNodes ) {
                                //load the XML in an iframe
                                var ifr = document.createElement('DIV');
                                ifr.style.visibility = 'hidden'; ifr.style.position = 'absolute'; ifr.style.top = '0px'; ifr.style.left = '0px';
                                //onload only fires in Opera so I use a timer for all
                                if( !window.MWJ_XML_timer ) { window.MWJ_XML_timer = window.setInterval('MWJ_checkXMLLoad();',100); }
                                ifr.innerHTML = '<iframe src="'+oURL+'" name="MWJ_XML_loader_'+MWJ_ldD.length+'" height="0" width="0"><\/iframe>';
                                MWJ_ldD[MWJ_ldD.length] = oFunct+'MWJ_SPLIT'+(oDelay?oDelay:1)+'';
                                document.body.appendChild(ifr);
                                return true;
                }
                return false;
}
function MWJ_checkXMLLoad() {
                //check if each imported file is available (huge files may not have loaded completely - nothing I can do - use the delay to help)
                for( var x = 0; x < MWJ_ldD.length; x++ ) { if( MWJ_ldD[x] && window.frames['MWJ_XML_loader_'+x] ) {
                                setTimeout( MWJ_ldD[x].split('MWJ_SPLIT')[0] + '(window.frames.MWJ_XML_loader_'+x+'.window.document);', parseInt(MWJ_ldD[x].split('MWJ_SPLIT')[1]) );
                                MWJ_ldD[x] = false;
                } }
}
```

Comment: Is there any console output? Check the developer tools in IE and look for the log output. Edit your post to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if `xmlDoc` is undefined. The `importXML` function doesn't seem to pass the parameter to the `storeRoster` function. What does the `importXML` function look like? I'll try to help you further.

Also, where is `roster.xml` located?

Comment: importxml function, which is in a file called xml_import.js, has been added to the post.  As for roster.xml, it is in the same directory as the roster.htm

Comment: Jeff, Are you able to help me figure this out?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry! I will try to help you out as much as possible. I'm very busy today, but will try to find time in between :) is your script found here? http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/jslibs/importxml.js I read the instructions on top and they state you may have to pass a delay in the function. Could you try `importXML('roster.xml','storeRoster', false, 2000);`?

Comment: Thanks. I can try that. I wanted to restate that it currently works in Chrome, but not IE or FF.  I wasn't sure if that was clear before.

Comment: I tried this and it still has the same issue in IE and FF. It also still works fine in Chrome.